Couldn't get my desired output and got this kind of error 'htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given'
This is my data.
{"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorDescription":"Success","Data":[{"PluginType":"SMS","Credits":"৳48.959915"}]}

I want to get "Credits" value. Ex: ৳48.959915.
I used json_encode but Couldn't fetch Credits value.
I tried this,
$get_balance = '{"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorDescription":"Success","Data":[{"PluginType":"SMS","Credits":"৳48.959915"}]}'; $balance = json_decode($get_balance); echo $balance['Data']['Credits'];

Make it a string: $get_balance = '{"ErrorCode":0 ... '; - you're missing quotes

If you had error reporting enabled you'd see an Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "{" in ...

@brombeer I alreday make it string and got 'ErrorDescription' and 'ErrorCode' vlaue but couldn't fetch 'Credits' value

"but couldn't fetch 'Credits' value" Why not? How are you trying to access it? What happens, do you get an error? Blank page? Wrong result?

Got this error when I want to access 'Credits'  'htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given'

There is no call to htmlspecialchars() in the code you posted.

@Olivier I mentioned it on my title...When I want to get 'Credits' value I got this error. I tried to access it like this in laravel blade {{$balance->Credits}}

{{$balance->Credits}} Where does the Data part show up in this code?

You never mentioned you were using Blade. Please edit your question to add all relevant informations.

$jsonString = '{"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorDescription":"Success","Data":[{"PluginType":"SMS","Credits":"৳48.959915"}]}';

        // Convert JSON string to PHP array
        $dataArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);

        // Error checking
        if ($dataArray['ErrorCode'] === 0 && $dataArray['ErrorDescription'] === 'Success') {
            // Check if "Credits" key exists
            if (isset($dataArray['Data'][0]['Credits'])) {
                $credits = $dataArray['Data'][0]['Credits'];
                // Print the Credits value
                dd($credits); // Laravel's dd() function dumps the value and stops the script
            } else {
                dd("Credits key not found.");
            }
        } else {
            dd("Error: " . $dataArray['ErrorDescription']);
        }


@yasinkonok Cannot reproduce with the exact code posted here, it outputs '৳48.959915' as expected. You're probably missing , true in json_decode
